# Mulesoft not setting JMS type when publishing to Oracle queue

Tags: oracle, jms, mulesoft

I am publishing a message to an Oracle queue through JMS, and I am receiving this error:

```
JMS-108: Messages of type TextMessage not allowed with Destinations containing payload of type SYS.XMLTYPE
```

I have attempted to set the property `jmsType` on the publish module to `BytesMessage` yet it does not change the error.

There's not much more to expand on. I just cant seem to find another case of this issue after a lot of looking, and I really am having trouble finding what to try next so I felt it necessary to make a post here.

`payload.queue is the name of the oracle queue`
`payload.request_id is an integer`
`vars.xml is an application/xml variable`

```xml
<jms:publish doc:name="Publish" doc:id="an id" config-ref="jms_oracle_aq" destination="#[payload.queue]]" sendCorrelationId="ALWAYS">
     <jms:message outboundContentType="application/xml" correlationId="#[payload.request_id]" jmsType="BytesMessage">
          <jms:body><![CDATA[#[vars.xml]]]></jms:body>
     </jms:message>
</jms:publish>
```

```xml
<jms:config name="jms_oracle_aq" doc:name="JMS config" doc:id="an id">
     <jms:generic-connection connectionFactory="oraAQConnectionFactory" />
</jms:config>
```

```xml
<bean id="oraAQDataSource" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${oracle.aq.host}:${oracle.aq.port}/${oracle.aq.sid}" />
    <property name="user" value="${oracle.aq.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${oracle.aq.password}" />
    <property name="connectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="connectionWaitTimeout" value="5" />
    <property name="validateConnectionOnBorrow" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="oraAQConnectionFactory" class="oracle.jms.AQjmsConnectionFactory">
    <property name="datasource" ref="oraAQDataSource" />
</bean>
```

```
mule4

com.oracle.javavm.jrf
aqapi
19.3

com.oracle.javavm.jrf
ojdbc8
19.3

com.oracle.javavm.jrf
oracle.ucp
19.3

org.mule.connectors
mule-jms-connector
1.9
mule-plugin
```

Comment: Which message broker are you using? "Oracle queue" is not very clear. Please state product and version. Same for Mule version, and JMS connector version, and client library version. Also add the JMS Connector configuration to the question. Do you see any errors? What is the payload content and format?

Comment: @aled added a couple more things, I can't get too much into the specifics so forgive me if the versioning part is a little vague

Comment: Less details reduce the probability of someone being able to provide an answer.

Comment: Have you tried removing `outboundContentType`?

Comment: @aled just attempted that, no change to the error

Comment: What about setting it to outboundContentType="text/plain"? What is the queue expecting anyway?

Comment: @aled I have just attempted that change as well as seperately testing it with a `write(vars.xml, "application/xml")` replaceing the message. neither have changed the error. 
the queue is expecting SYS.XMLTYPE, an oracle data type

Comment: I suspect this is not supported by Mule. You may need to change the queue to accept the message type as it is or implement a second queue and transform the message between the two using Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: How did you create the queue table in your Oracle AQ? If it _jms_text_message then you might need to encode the xml document into a string (i.e. < will become &lt;) and set the content type as text/plain. Another solution might be to change the payload type in your queue table to sys.aq$_jms-message to support all message types.